# Pycharm Process finished with exit code 0 instead of actual output

Tags: python, pycharm

So i have created a very basic python price getting bot but it doesnt actually show any results instead it just says Process finished with exit code 0
Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal
from gemini.gemini_core.gemini_master import Gemini
from gemini.helpers import poloniex, analyze


def cmo_trading_strategy(data, gemini):
    pass


# TODO optimise params

PAIR = "BTC_USD"
PERIOD = 300
DAYS_HISTORY = 100


params = {
    'capital_base': 100,
    'data_frequency': 'D',
    'fees': {
        'open_fee': 0.01,
        'close_fee': 0.01
    }
}

if __name__ == '_main__':
    def_df = poloniex.load_dataframe(pair=PAIR, period=PERIOD, days_history=DAYS_HISTORY)

    backtesting_engine = Gemini(Logic=cmo_trading_strategy, sim_params=params, analyze=analyze.analyze_bokeh)
    backtesting_engine.run(data=data_df)

    print(data_df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without testing i think you got a typo:

```
def_df = poloniex.load_dataframe(pair=PAIR, period=PERIOD, days_history=DAYS_HISTORY)
```

should be:

```
data_df = poloniex.load_dataframe(pair=PAIR, period=PERIOD, days_history=DAYS_HISTORY)
```